# local array length is different from when it is called from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, decltype

In the following code, `std::extent<decltype(columns)>::value` calculates the length of the given array. However, when the array is a function argument, the compiler behaves in different way. Could some one help me how to fix it?

output:

> local array length: 5
>
> function array length: 0

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void showcolumns_num(std::string columns[])
{
    int columns_num=std::extent<decltype(columns)>::value;
    std::cout<<"function array length: "<<columns_num<<std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::string column_list[]={"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"};

    // local calculation of column number
    int columns_num=std::extent<decltype(column_list)>::value;
    std::cout<<"local array length: "<<columns_num<<std::endl;

    // function calculation of column number
    showcolumns_num(column_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays decays to *pointers* when passed to a function.

Comment: So there must be no way to calculate it inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass array by reference to avoid the decay to pointer which so loses size information:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void showcolumns_num(std::string (&columns)[N])
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/DANtLw).

Comment: Thank you very much. Also `N` must be used instead of `std::extent<decltype(columns)>::value`. Just could you tell me why `(&columns)[N]` cannot be replaced with `columns[N]`?

Comment: @barej As function parameters, `string (&columns)[N]` is a reference to an array of `N` strings. `string columns[N]` is a pointer to a `string` - it's equivalent to `string* columns`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: Don't use arrays. Instead of `string columns[N];`, use `vector<string> columns;` or `vector<string> columns(N,"");`. In this answer, I'll talk a bit more about arrays, they are "interesting". But arrays are "interesting" in the way that cancer is interesting, somebody has to understand cancer, but we want to get rid of it and most people don't want to be experts.

C arrays are really weird things. They can't be passed by value, but they can be passed by reference, and C++ makes it quite easy. If you are determined - as an intellectual exercise - to pass arrays, then you can use this:

```
 template<size_t N>
 void showcolumns_num(std::string (&columns)[N])
```

Non-array types, like `int`, or `struct Person`, or `list<vector<string>>`, can be passed by value *or* by reference. But arrays cannot be passed by value.

If you attempt to pass an array by value, the compiler will do a trick where it will instead pass a pointer to the first element of the array. This is called *pointer decay*.

This means that, without warning, the compiler will rewrite your function declarations

```
void showcolumns_num(std::string columns[]) { // this is what you write
// changed to
void showcolumns_num(std::string* columns) { // ... but this is what you get
```

and every call to `showcolumns_num` will be changed from:

```
showcolumns_num(column_list); // this is what you write
// changed to
showcolumns_num(&(column_list[0])); // ... but this is what you get
```

The reason behind this is historical, and is related to an earlier language called B.

Variables are declared as local variables, or as global variables, or as function parameters. For local and global variables, the compiler will generally respect your wishes, but not for function parameters:

```
void foo(int x[5]) { // silently converted to  int *x
    int y[10];       // y really will be an array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That because of the declaration:

```
void showcolumns_num(std::string columns[])
```

is the same as:

```
void showcolumns_num(std::string * columns)
```

But declaration:

```
std::string column_list[]={"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"};
```

is the same as:

```
std::string column_list[5]={"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"};
```

So compiler doesn't know about array size inside the function.
Just use the `std::vector< std::string >`.